# SSL blocking my website

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, cpanel

This morning when I try to access my website using https it says: https://--example-- is requesting your username and password. The site says: “Protected Folder”

I haven't changed nothing and in the cpanel I don't have any protected folder. Does anyone know what it can be?

Thanks

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.example2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.secure\.example2\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/secure\.example2\.com\/rent\/whitelable\.cfm\?WL\=3" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you'll have to ask from your hosting. We can't know.

Comment: This is a basic authentication request, has nothing to do with SSL.

Check your web folder for a file called .htaccess and post the contents

Comment: I just added .htacchess. example2 is the name of my website

Comment: cpanel updates can break everything, I've seen that happen myself, it's why I won't touch any client that uses it, unless they are moving to a professional hoster to get away from it, as soon as possible. This issue has nothing to do with ssl, as other comments note as well.